# Rails 3: Simple form start date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Im using simple form in my app to get the users birthday.

It is set (and I want to keep it this way) to go back to year 1900 but I was wondering if there is a way to have the default start be like 1950 (they can still scroll back to older if they need) so most users dont have to scroll so far to get to their age.

```
  <%= f.input :date_of_birth, :as => :date, :start_year => 1900,
    :end_year => Date.today.year - 12,
    :order => [ :day, :month, :year], :required => true %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can just switch the :start_year value with the :end_year value to have

```
 <%= f.input :date_of_birth, :as => :date, :start_year => Date.today.year - 12,
:end_year => 1900,
:order => [ :day, :month, :year], :required => true %>
```

As the :start_year and :end_year is just the way you display the year...

Answer (score 1):

i think datetime_select http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select will be the one you need and set :default => {:year => 1950 } to what year you want to be shown as default start

Answer (score 0):

You can use date_select http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html

and use the :default option